# jQuery if not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, get

I have a jQuery function that uses ajax to get data, then displays it, I want to use an if statement to determine if the function has already been run, if it has, a certain section of the function doesn't run again, for some reason, the if statement is being ignored.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 1;
$(function() {
   if(a<2) {
         $('.notifications').click(function() {
             $('#notifications2').show();
             $('#loader').show();
                 $.get('/getnotifications.php', function(data) {
                 $(".getnot").append(data);
                 $('#loader').hide();
                 a++; 
                 });
           });
           }
    });
</script>
```

Any idea why this is failing to work?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with console.log() on your get request and the a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're placing the `if` statement at the wrong point, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 1;
$(function() {
    $('.notifications').click(function() {
        if(a<2) {
            $('#notifications2').show();
            $('#loader').show();
            $.get('/getnotifications.php', function(data) {
                $(".getnot").append(data);
                $('#loader').hide();
                a++;
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

You're current code is simply checking that `a` is less than 2 when the document first loads, not every time you click on `.notifications`.